# Silverlight Implicit styling in ControlLibrary items

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I've got a Silverlight class library which contains ResourceDictionary objects with styles that I want to propagate throughout my Silverlight application. Let's call it the Theme Library. I want to use implicit styling in the Theme Library to style every control in the application.

This is simple to do for all the controls in the main application, just by adding the Theme Library ResourceDictionaries to the App.xaml's ResourceDictionary as MergedDictionaries.
The problem I have is that I have a ControlLibrary which defines DefaultStyleKey s for some controls. Unfortunately the styles in the ControlLibrary resort back to the default styling of any controls that they are composed of and I can't change this.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: I've solved this issue. I had to add the Theme's ResourceDictionary as a merged dictionary on each ResourceDictionary in the ControlLibrary as well as in the main application. (Sorry not a comment, but an answer!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this issue. I had to add the Theme's ResourceDictionary as a merged dictionary on each ResourceDictionary in the ControlLibrary as well as in the main application.

In other words the Theme's ResourceDictionary was a root ResourceDictionary which is referenced by elements both in the ControlLibrary and the application.

Unfortunately default styling didn't propagate through ControlLibrary elements, so I had to manually wire up each of the controls I wanted styling in the ControlLibrary.